# PDFBox xmpMetadata in C#

Tags: c#, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBOx to create accessible PDF document.Can anyone please help me to include XMP Metadata using PDFBox in C#?
Followed https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/pdfacreation.html.

```
XMPMetadata xmp = new XMPMetadata();
XMPSchemaPDFAId pdfaid = new XMPSchemaPDFAId(xmp);
xmp.addSchema(pdfaid);
pdfaid.setConformance("B");
pdfaid.setPart(1);
pdfaid.setAbout("");
javax.imageio.metadata.importXMPMetadata(xmp);
```

Used above code segment. But I got error, "importXMPMetadata does not exist in javax.imageio.metadata ".

Comment: Why `javax.imageio.metadata` ? `metadata`is created with `PDMetadata metadata = new PDMetadata(doc);`

Comment: It is working. Thanks so much  @TilmanHausherr

Comment: I need to create PDF/UA document  using PDFBox. How can i do this setting metadata?

Comment: Sorry I don't know about PDF/UA, I would have to look that up myself. Better ask a new question. Please answer this one yourself, I don't use C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below scenario is worked for me. As described by @TilmanHausherr, metadata is created with PDMetadata metadata = new PDMetadata(doc);

```
XMPMetadata xmp = new XMPMetadata();
XMPSchemaPDFAId pdfaid = new XMPSchemaPDFAId(xmp);
xmp.addSchema(pdfaid);
pdfaid.setConformance("B");
pdfaid.setPart(1);
pdfaid.setAbout("");
PDMetadata metadata = new PDMetadata(doc);
metadata.importXMPMetadata(xmp);
```